# Flutter searchable_dropdown Ui not updating on click of a button and setState() is called inside the onPressed() of the Button

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I am creating 2 Searchable dropdown and swapping the values of the 2 Dropdown on click of a IconButton, the values are swapping but the ui doesn't gets changed when i am calling setState() function inside the onPressed() of the button :

Below is my code :
pubspec.yaml dependencies : searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:searchable_dropdown/searchable_dropdown.dart';


class MainDashBoardTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainDashBoardTabState createState() => _MainDashBoardTabState();
}

class _MainDashBoardTabState extends State<MainDashBoardTab> {
  String fromPlaceSelected = "";
  String toPlaceSelected = "";
  List<String> fromPlaceItemsString = [
    "Borivali",
    "Kandivali",
    "Malad",
    "Andheri",
    "Dadar"
  ];
  List<String> toPlaceItemsString = [
    "Kankavli",
    "Pune",
    "Solapur",
    "Manmad",
    "Belgaum",
    "Kolhapur"
  ];

  List<DropdownMenuItem> items = [];
  List<DropdownMenuItem> items1 = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < fromPlaceItemsString.length; i++) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(fromPlaceItemsString[i]),
        value: fromPlaceItemsString[i],
      ));
      fromPlaceSelected = fromPlaceItemsString[fromPlaceItemsString.length - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toPlaceItemsString.length; i++) {
      items1.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(toPlaceItemsString[i]),
        value: toPlaceItemsString[i],
      ));
      toPlaceSelected = toPlaceItemsString[toPlaceItemsString.length - 1];
    }
  }

  fromPlaceWidget() {
    return SearchableDropdown.single(
      items: items,
      value: fromPlaceSelected,
      hint: "Select From Place ",
      searchHint: "Select From Place",
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          fromPlaceSelected = value;
        });
      },
      isExpanded: true,
    );
  }

  toPlaceWidget() {
    return SearchableDropdown.single(
      items: items1,
      value: toPlaceSelected,
      hint: "Select To Place",
      searchHint: "Select To Place",
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          toPlaceSelected = value;
        });
      },
      isExpanded: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
        height: 250,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      fromPlaceWidget(),
                      toPlaceWidget(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.swap_vert),
                    iconSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        String temp = fromPlaceSelected;
                        fromPlaceSelected = toPlaceSelected;
                        toPlaceSelected = temp;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 different Lists. So even after swapping the values, the new values are not presented in the lists. You will also have to swap the list or better swap the whole widgets.